# Ошибка доступа git push-а

Tags: git, ssh-key

Всем привет!

Нужно было сделать экспорт данных из удаленной mysql базы(доступ через ssh) 
Я взял MySql-Workbench и в нем при подключении указал на свой /home/serge/.ssh/id_rsa.pub файл
При коннекте MySql-Workbench выдал сообщение что нет доступа к config-файлу 
Я установл для config-файла полный доступ для всех юзеров и благополучно сделал экспорт из удаленной базы

Теперь в проекте при попытке залить изменения на git получаю ошибки:

```
$ git push
Bad owner or permissions on /home/serge/.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$ sudo git push
[sudo] password for serge: 
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


root@serge:/home/serge/.ssh# ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root    95 чер 25 16:50 config
-rw------- 1 serge serge 1679 чер 25 16:39 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 serge serge  393 чер 25 16:39 id_rsa.pub
-rwxrwxrwx 1 serge serge 2782 лип 18 17:13 known_hosts
```

и в /home/serge/.ssh/config :

```
Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_rsa

Host github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_rsa
```

Не понятно почему ошибка и как ее починить ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если права на файлы `~/.ssh`  "превышены", установить соединение становиться невозможным.

С некоторыми вариациями, но всё же, вот минимальный порог прав на файлы и директорию `~/.ssh`, начните с него:

```
 # этого достаточно для работы   
.ssh -  700 (drwx------)
   id_rsa.pub - public key 644 (-rw-r--r--)
   id_rsa - private key 600 (-rw-------)
   authorized_keys - (-rw-------)
   config - 600 (-rw-------)
   known_hosts - 600 (-rw-------)
```

И конечно пользователь должен быть владельцем этих файлов.

> Да, на некоторые из файлов можно и не устанавливать ограниченные права, но лучше соблюдать общие правила безопасности.

Для вывода подробной информации при ssh-соединении, используем `-v`

```
ssh -v user@host
```